# Qgis-bin-exe -Application error

Tags: qgis, error, windows

I have installed QGIS 3.8.2 and when I opened the problem is : Qgis-bin-exe -Application error . How should I fix it ?

---

If I install newest version , Can I work to the project that I worked in 3.8.2 ?

Comment: QGIS 3.8.2 is no longer supported. I'd suggest to upgrade to one of the currently supported versions.